# Unable to run alacritty using nix

Tags: nix, alacritty

```
 .nix-profile/bin/alacritty   
    Error: Error creating GL context; Received multiple errors:
    Could not create EGL display object
    `glXQueryExtensionsString` found no glX extensions

Error: "Event loop terminated with code: 1"
```

Running debian stable and installed alacritty using nix package manager

Some users suggest using this - https://github.com/guibou/nixGL. But i get this error

```
  nix-channel --add https://github.com/guibou/nixGL/archive/main.tar.gz nixgl && nix-channel --update
warning: unable to download 'https://cache.nixos.org/v5djb4jw3hg4brdbidqaspin8n8isyq6.narinfo': SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (60); retrying in 259 ms
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/gm6gq44ivdqgmrsvlsr08d2nqjircgds-nixgl.drv
building '/nix/store/gm6gq44ivdqgmrsvlsr08d2nqjircgds-nixgl.drv'...
while setting up the build environment: executing '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
builder for '/nix/store/gm6gq44ivdqgmrsvlsr08d2nqjircgds-nixgl.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/gm6gq44ivdqgmrsvlsr08d2nqjircgds-nixgl.drv' failed
error: program '/usr/bin/nix-build' failed with exit code 100
```

Comment: Usually it happens because of outdated drivers. Updating the system helps.

Answer (score 1):

try installing opengl drivers for nix os
https://github.com/nix-community/nixGL from this repo.
once is successful try installing pkg again.
Workaround - git clone the alacritty repo and `cargo build --release` inside nix shell should build alacritty successfully inside nix shell